# Problem assign optional value es6 coalescing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

How can I assign an optional value in undefined case object attribute value.

something like this.

```
const { someField } = { y: "Hello" } || { someField: "hello!"}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2) like `const { someField = 'hello!' } = { y: "Hello" }`?

Comment: What value is supposed to be undefined here? You aren't doing any comparations?

Comment: I need that: console.log(someField); // hello!

Comment: Your question is unclear. As it's written `{ y: "Hello" }` will be returned every time because it's a [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. Is this what you're trying to do: `const { someField = "hello" } = { y: "Hello" }`

Comment: The correct answer for me was:
const { someField } = Object.assign({someField: "Hello"}, { y: 'Hola' });
console.log(someField) // "Hello"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [destructuring assignments default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2). In this case, as you want the default value to be the value in `{ someField: "hello!"}` you can assign it to be the default value by referencing it as an object.

See example below:

```js
const obj = { someField: "hello!"};
const {someField = obj['someField']} = { y: "Hello" };
console.log(someField); // hello!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to first merge the different objects, where the rightmost objects will overwrite the objects to the left, then use destructuring to extract the property from the merged object:

```js
const defaultValues = { y: 'Hello', someField: 'hello!' };
const { someField, y } = Object.assign(defaultValues, { someField: 'bye!' });

console.log(y, someField);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this function to check null or undefined given value

```
function checkNullOrUndefined(value){
    if(value ==null || value===''  || value== "undefined" || value === undefined) 
        return false;
    return true;
}

var a = {};
const b = checkNullOrUndefined(a) ? true : false
```

Answer (score 0):

two posibles ways finally works for me:

First one:
const { someField } = Object.assign({someField: "Hello"}, { y: 'Hola' });

Better this
const { someField } = {someField: { y: "bla bla" } || {someField: "Hello"} }